# How to integrate firebase-auth to verify phone number

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have created phone number verify screen and now I want to integrate firebase-auth for verifying phone number via OTP. But I have no idea how to do that, Please help me with it.

I have tried to find tutorial and example, but those were not helpful for me.

> Phone Verify Screen

```
import React from 'react';  
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, BackHandler, Alert, AsyncStorage, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';  
import HandleBack from '../component/backHandler';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class BuyerVerify extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getData();
    };

    onBack = () => {
        return true;
    };

    getData = () => {
        const getNumber = async () => {
            let number = '';
            try {
                number = await AsyncStorage.getItem('number');
            } catch (error) {
              // Error retrieving data
              console.log(error.message);
            }
            //return number;
            alert(number);
        }
        getNumber();
    };    

    render(){
        return(
            <HandleBack onBack={this.onBack}>
            <View style={styles.root}>
            <View style={styles.outer}>

                <View style={styles.inner}>

                    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}> 
                    <TextInput style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Enter OTP"
                        placeholderTextColor="#939eaf"
                        keyboardType="phone-pad"
                     />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button1Container}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            Verify Buyer
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button2Container} onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            Change number
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

                </View>

            </View>
            </View>
            </HandleBack>
        );
    }
}
export default BuyerVerify;
```

I want to verify phone number via OTP using firebase.

Answer (score 0):

From Firebase's PhoneAuthProvider interface:

```
// 'recaptcha-container' is the ID of an element in the DOM.
var applicationVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
    'recaptcha-container');
var provider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
provider.verifyPhoneNumber('+16505550101', applicationVerifier)
    .then(function(verificationId) {
      var verificationCode = window.prompt('Please enter the verification ' +
          'code that was sent to your mobile device.');
      return firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId,
          verificationCode);
    })
    .then(function(phoneCredential) {
      return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(phoneCredential);
    });
```